Cypress not able to select radio button
I'm using cypress with typescript.Not able to click/check the radio button in the dialog box

HTML
<div _ngcontent-ng-c3278589420="" class="dialog-container"><div _ngcontent-ng-c3278589420="" class="content-container"><div _ngcontent-ng-c3278589420="" class="title">Change the current stop sequence?</div><div _ngcontent-ng-c3278589420="" class="content"><span _ngcontent-ng-c3278589420="" class="supporting-text"> With the addition of the new stop(s) on an existing route, would you like to- </span><mat-radio-group _ngcontent-ng-c3278589420="" role="radiogroup" class="mat-mdc-radio-group radio-buttons"><mat-radio-button _ngcontent-ng-c3278589420="" value="1" ngdefaultcontrol="" class="mat-mdc-radio-button mat-accent ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" id="mat-radio-38"><div mat-internal-form-field="" class="mdc-form-field mat-internal-form-field"><div class="mdc-radio"><div class="mat-mdc-radio-touch-target"></div><input type="radio" class="mdc-radio__native-control" id="mat-radio-38-input" name="mat-radio-group-36" value="1" tabindex="0"><div class="mdc-radio__background"><div class="mdc-radio__outer-circle"></div><div class="mdc-radio__inner-circle"></div></div><div mat-ripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-radio-ripple mat-mdc-focus-indicator"><div class="mat-ripple-element mat-radio-persistent-ripple"></div></div></div><label class="mdc-label" for="mat-radio-38-input"> Keep the existing sequence number of the current stops. </label></div></mat-radio-button><mat-radio-button _ngcontent-ng-c3278589420="" value="2" ngdefaultcontrol="" class="mat-mdc-radio-button mat-accent ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" id="mat-radio-39"><div mat-internal-form-field="" class="mdc-form-field mat-internal-form-field"><div class="mdc-radio"><div class="mat-mdc-radio-touch-target"></div><input type="radio" class="mdc-radio__native-control" id="mat-radio-39-input" name="mat-radio-group-36" value="2" tabindex="0"><div class="mdc-radio__background"><div class="mdc-radio__outer-circle"></div><div class="mdc-radio__inner-circle"></div></div><div mat-ripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-radio-ripple mat-mdc-focus-indicator"><div class="mat-ripple-element mat-radio-persistent-ripple"></div></div></div><label class="mdc-label" for="mat-radio-39-input"> Adjust the sequence of current stops </label></div></mat-radio-button></mat-radio-group></div></div><div _ngcontent-ng-c3278589420="" class="buttons"><div _ngcontent-ng-c3278589420="" class="green-text-btn">Cancel</div><div _ngcontent-ng-c3278589420="" class="orange-text-btn disabled-text-btn"> Add Stops </div></div></div>

I tried below ways but not working
  cy.get('mat-radio-group > mat-radio-button[value="1"] input[type="radio"]') 
                .find('input[type="radio"]') 
                .check({ force: true }); 

cy.get("mat-radio-group > mat-radio-button")
  .first()
  .check({ force: true }); 

cy.get('input[type="radio"][value="2"]')
  .first()
  .check({ force: true }); 

cy.get('input[type="radio"][value="2"]')
  .check({ force: true }); 

cy.get('[value="1"]')
  .first()
  .check({ force: true }); 

I have added enough waits. I'm not able to find it. So requesting help on clicking a radio button

In the picture you have a overlay covering the elements, probably from a popup like cookie consent. Your error message will indicate that to you. Getting rid of the overlay allows the test to pass.

The picture was taken with dev tools and I had debugger running. Hence the picture looks like overlay. However, the image is for reference

The mistake is in the first selector (or the second query, depending on how you look at it).
You have used:
cy.get('mat-radio-group > mat-radio-button[value="1"] input[type="radio"]') 
  .find('input[type="radio"]') 
  .check();

but it fails because input[type="radio"] is in both the cy.get() and the .find(), but there is only one input[type="radio"].
To fix your error change to
cy.get('mat-radio-group > mat-radio-button[value="1"]') 
  .find('input[type="radio"]') 
  .check();

or
cy.get('mat-radio-group > mat-radio-button[value="1"] input[type="radio"]') 
  .check();

@Prabhacker, here is the log from the passing test, based on the HTML you have posted in the question:


No, tried the above, it didn't work.

Yes actually it does work. I'll post the test log for you.
